# R fill percentage in geom_point

Tags: r, ggplot2, geometry, percentage, point

I would like to make a circle chart where the values in the `rec` column correspond to the percentage of the circle that should be filled with the black color. I made an example in Photoshop (see obs A and B in figure 1).
In my searches I found some explanations for `bar_plot`, but none of them worked in my script

Would anyone know how to do this or suggest another chart option that would demonstrate what I wanted?

```
ggplot(Dataset, aes(sp,log(num))) + 
  geom_point(aes(size = pref, color=as.factor(ex)), shape = 21, stroke = 2)+
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(4,10)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("black", "red")) + # set the border to the bg color
  ggthemes::theme_few() +
  guides(color = FALSE) + # remove the legend for the border
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = .5))
```

Data:

```
grupo   sp  num porc_rec    rec pref    ex
ave A   47  74.46808511 35  7   0
ave B 22    22.72727273 5   3   0
ave C   5   0   0   0   0
ave D   4   0   0   0   0
ave E   2   0   0   0   0
ave F   2   0   0   0   0
ave G   2   0   0   0   1
ave H   2   0   0   0   0
ave I   1   0   0   1   0
ave J   1   0   0   0   0
ave L 1 0   0   0   0
ave M   1   0   0   0   0
ave N   1   0   0   0   0
ave O   1   0   0   0   0
ave P   1   0   0   0   0
ave Q   1   0   0   0   0
ave R   1   0   0   0   0
ave S   1   0   0   0   1
ave T   1   0   0   0   1
ave U   1   0   0   0   1
```

[image]

Comment: You could try `scatterpie` if the form of the fill effect can be flexible: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/scatterpie/vignettes/scatterpie.html

Comment: Using fill height to represent percentage (as per your example) can be tricky. For example, if a value is 25%, would the point be filled up to 1/4 of the height, or 1/4 of the area?

Comment: @desc you mean to do something like that?
ggplot(Dataset, aes(sp,log(num))) + 
  geom_point(aes(size = pref, color=as.factor(ex)), shape = 21, stroke = 2)+
  geom_scatterpie(aes(fill=rec)) +

Comment: @Z.Lin Thank you very much for the feedback, but I had a question. To accomplish the command you suggested I should change the way my worksheet is organized?

Comment: @FranBraga I have no idea how your worksheet is organized, nor have I suggested any specific command since I'm unsure what you really want to achieve. What I do suggest is for you to check whether `geom_scatterpie` (as recommended by desc) suits your needs, work on that, & come back to post a new question if you run into *specific* problems with your code. Broad questions asking for recommendations have a tendency to get closed on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `scatterpie` package you can generate something similar to what you asked for (the radius scaling isn't perfect but should be adjustable to get the results you want:

```
dat = structure(list(group = c("ave", "ave", "ave", "ave", "ave", "ave", 
        "ave", "ave", "ave", "ave", "ave", "ave", "ave", "ave", "ave", 
        "ave", "ave", "ave", "ave", "ave"), sp = c("A", "B", "C", "D", 
        "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", 
        "S", "T", "U"), num = c(47L, 22L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), porc_rec = c(74.46808511, 
        22.72727273, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0), rec = c(35L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
        0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), pref = c(7L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
        0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
        ex = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
        0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
        -20L))

library(ggplot2)
library(scatterpie)

dat$idx = as.numeric(1:nrow(dat))

input = dat[,c("idx","num","porc_rec","ex","pref")]
input$recip = 100 - input$porc_rec
input$radius = abs(0.4 / scale((input$pref + 1)/ max(input$pref),center = 7))
ggplot() + geom_scatterpie(data=input, aes(x=idx, y=log(num),color = factor(ex), r = radius), cols=c("porc_rec","recip")) +
  coord_equal() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("black","white")) + scale_colour_manual(values = c("black","red"))
```

[image]